# jQuery Form Plugin Passing in original form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm using the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api) and trying to figure out why I can't use the find method within the success function.

```
           $('#signup-form').ajaxForm({
           beforeSubmit: function (arr, $form, options) {
               $form.find("input[name=email]").css('width', '170');
               $form.find("input[type=submit]").val('Subscribing...').attr('disabled', 'true');
           },
           target: "#signup-form-wrap",
           dataType: 'json', 
           success: function (data, $form) {
               $form.find("input[type=submit]").val('Go!').css('width', '200');

           }
       });
```

For some reason, I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object success has no method 'find'`

When I alert $form, it's value is just the string 'success'. It does work in beforeSubmit, however. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object) the second parameter passed to the success-function is statusText, which sounds like what you are logging. These are the parameters passed to the success-function according to the documentation:

```
1.) responseText or responseXML value (depending on the value of the dataType option).
2.) statusText
3.) xhr (or the jQuery-wrapped form element if using jQuery < 1.4)
4.) jQuery-wrapped form element (or undefined if using jQuery < 1.4)
```

So I guess your success-function would be something like this:

```
success: function (data, status, xhr, $form) {
   $form.find("input[type=submit]").val('Go!').css('width', '200');    
}
```

Comment: That was extremely quick. I'll accept when the time limit is up. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery Form Plugin Documentation: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object

> **success**
>
> Callback function to be invoked after the form has been submitted. If a 'success' callback function is provided it is invoked after the response has been returned from the server. It is passed the following arguments:
>
> 1.) responseText or responseXML value (depending on the value of the dataType option).
>   2.) statusText
>   3.) xhr (or the jQuery-wrapped form element if using jQuery < 1.4)
>   4.) jQuery-wrapped form element (or undefined if using jQuery < 1.4)
>
> Default value: null

Based on that information you may want to try the following:

***note the changes to the params being sent to success**

```
$('#signup-form').ajaxForm({
  beforeSubmit: function (arr, $form, options) {
    $form.find("input[name=email]").css('width', '170');
    $form.find("input[type=submit]").val('Subscribing...').attr('disabled', 'true');
  },
  target: "#signup-form-wrap",
  dataType: 'json', 
  success: function (data, statusText, xhr, $form) {
    $form.find("input[type=submit]").val('Go!').css('width', '200');
  }
});
```